# Attach the event on click to his father with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Newby to pure JS.

I'm creating a menu that has to work with mobile.

I'm trying to create with pure .js, instead of using jQuery so, that's an experiment and it has been challenging.

Here's my code:

JS:

```
(function() {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');
  var subMenu = {
    downToggle: document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu'),
    downToggleTitle: document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-title'),
    subMenuItems: document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu-item-mobile'),
    searchBar: document.getElementById('mobile-search'),
    onclickimg: document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu-arrow'),
  };
  function listen() {
    for(var i=0; i<subMenu.downToggleTitle.length; i++) {
      subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // if there is a menu that's already open and it's not the element that's been clicked, close it before opening the selected menu
        for(var i=0; i<subMenu.downToggleTitle.length; i++) {
          if (subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).classList.contains('expanded') && subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i) !== e.target) {
            subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).classList.toggle('expanded');
          }
        }

        // inside each sub-menu is a third-level-sub-menu. So inside each sub-menu we
        // check if it's already open, then close it
        for(var i=0; i<subMenu.subMenuItems.length; i++) {
          // console.log("test test")
          if(subMenu.subMenuItems.item(i).classList.contains('expanded') && subMenu.subMenuItems.item(i) !== e.target) {
            subMenu.subMenuItems.item(i).classList.toggle('expanded');
          }
        }
        this.classList.toggle('expanded');
      });
    }

    for(var i=0; i<subMenu.subMenuItems.length; i++) {
      subMenu.subMenuItems.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        for(var i=0; i<subMenu.subMenuItems.length; i++) {
          if(subMenu.subMenuItems[i].classList.contains('expanded') && subMenu.subMenuItems[i] !== e.target) {
            subMenu.subMenuItems[i].classList.toggle('expanded');
            console.log("hello Aug 20");
          }
        }
        this.classList.toggle('expanded');
      });
    }
  } listen();
}());
```

The behavior that I want to change is the following:

In the first version, if the client press the `.sub-menu-title` class (the variable `downToggleTitle`), which is a `li` item, the very element will toggle the class `expanded`. Now I want something a little bit different.

I added the class `sub-menu-arrow`, which is the variable `onclickimg` to an `img` at the very end of my list element, so if the client will click on the arrow, all the class element `sub-menu-title` ( `var = downToggleTitle` ) will toggle the class `expanded`.

This is not happening because for some reason if I change the code in this way:

```
subMenu.onclickimg.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        for(var i=0; i<subMenu.downToggleTitle.length; i++) {
          if (subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).classList.contains('expanded') && subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i) !== e.target) {
            subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).classList.toggle('expanded');
          }
        }
```

the class `expanded` will be toggled to the `sub-menu-arrow` elements (like I said, some images with animations).

Any suggestion on how to target the parent element in this case?

Also, is it possible to exclude the anchor element with the class `mobile-toplevel-link` from the click event?

The `<a>` element is the other children of the `sub-menu-title` class

Comment: DOM is gender neutral. There is no father, nor mother. Just parents. Other than that, it would really help if you provided some HTML

Comment: Have you tried using `.parentElement`?

Comment: Fair enough for the gender neutral 

Comment: yes, but where.. subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).parentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e)

Comment: Where you want to select the parent element of the current element, e.g., `subMenu.downToggleTitle.item(i).parentElement` or storing the appropriate parent element in `subMenu`

Comment: Also, when you do `for(var i...) { el[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ ... i ...}) }`, `i` will always be the last one, inside your click handler. Use a closure: `for(...) { (function(i){ el[i].addEvent... })(i); }`

Comment: @blex—you mean break the closure. Can also be done with `let i = 0` rather than `var` and avoid the function expression and call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a comment. You can greatly simplify your code using the iterator functionality of modern NodeLists. I don't see the point of the *subMenu* object, it just makes references longer.

Also, I've replaced *getElementsByClassName* as it produces a live NodeList, whereas *querySelectorAll* returns a static list. Not much difference here, but can be significant in other cases.

The following is a simple refactoring, it should work exactly as your current code is supposed to. Note that for arrow functions, *this* is adopted from the enclosing execution context.

```js
(function() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');
  let downToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu'),
    downToggleTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu-title'),
    subMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu-item-mobile'),
    searchBar = document.getElementById('mobile-search'),
    onclickimg = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu-arrow');

  function listen() {
    downToggleTitle.forEach(dtTitle => {
      dtTitle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // If there is a menu that's already open
        // and it's not the element that's been clicked,
        // close it before opening the selected menu
        downToggleTitle.forEach(node => {
          if (node.classList.contains('expanded') && node !== this) {
            node.classList.toggle('expanded');
          }
        });

        // inside each sub-menu is a third-level-sub-menu. So inside each sub-menu
        // If it's already open, close it
        subMenuItems.forEach(item => {
          // console.log("test test")
          if (item.classList.contains('expanded') && item !== this) {
            item.classList.toggle('expanded');
          }
        });
        this.classList.toggle('expanded');
      });
    });

    subMenuItems.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        subMenuItems.forEach(item => {
          if (items.classList.contains('expanded') && item !== this) {
            item.classList.toggle('expanded');
            console.log("hello Aug 20");
          }
        });
        this.classList.toggle('expanded');
      });
    });
  }
  listen();
}());
```

Comment: Just a great solution!!

Last thing that I asked in my question.. Is there any way to exclude the anchor element from the click event? the <a> element is the child of the sub-menu-title class

Comment: @user3833012—events bubble up the DOM (they go down too but very, very few listeners are set for that phase). If the A is above the LI, you can have the LI listener [*stopPropagation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Alternatively, you can put a listener on the A element and check the *event.target*: if it's not the A element or an immediate decedent, ignore it using [*preventDefault*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parent element of the clicked target, then you can exploit your current `eventListener` and use the `e.target.parentNode` to get it. This will return you an element, which you can add/remove CSS classes from and do pretty much everything you like. Keep in mind, you can use the `.parentNode` multiple times and for example, if you wanted to get the "grandparent" of an element (2 levels up) you could write `e.target.parentNode.parentNode` and so on.

Comment: Within a listener added by *addEventListener*, *e.target* is *this*, which is less to type and doesn't require capturing the event. ;-)